# Keep the header hidden if the scroll up is less than 40px

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code

```
  var header = document.querySelector('.page-header');
  if (!header) {
    return;
  }

  var scrollPrev = 0;

  window.onscroll = function () {
    var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
    if (scrolled > 100 && scrolled > scrollPrev) {
      header.classList.add('page-header--fixed');
    } else {
      header.classList.remove('page-header--fixed');
    }
    scrollPrev = scrolled;
  };
```

where the 'page-header--fixed' class makes the header sticky (appear). Everything works smoothly but I can't figure out a way to solve the following:
When I scroll up the page, I want to make the header sticky ONLY if I scrolled more than 40px. How can I do that?

Comment: `if (scrollPrev > scrolled + 40)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove or add the header.

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 40) {
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
          header.classList.add('page-header--fixed');
      } else {
          header.classList.remove('page-header--fixed');  
      }
        prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
}
```